# MVC vs. Active Record vs. Factory

Tags: design-patterns, activerecord, model-view-controller, factory

The active record pattern is an approach to accessing data in a database. A database table or view is wrapped into a class. Thus, an object instance is tied to a single row in the table. After creation of an object, a new row is added to the table upon save.

MVC is a framework for building web applications using a MVC (Model View Controller) design: The Model represents the application core (for instance a list of database records). The View displays the data (the database records).

In Factory pattern, we create object without exposing the creation logic to the client and refer to newly created object using a common interface.

What are the benefits of using MVC comparing to Active Record ?

In my website i used a combination of Active Record & Factory patterns. For me, it's more simple and faster to use these because i just need to write some functions. Also, i don't need a view, a model or something else. I mean in my opinion, the more i'm bounded to rules, the more designing becomes complicated.

But if what i say is correct, why there are too many frameworks that use MVC ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 3 are completely unrelated.

MVC is an Software Architectural Pattern that can be used for all kinds of UI. This pattern is used to define the internal architecture of an application. The model is not the object that is mapped to the database, but the *View Model* which is used to ship data from the Domain to the UI.

Active Record is a Integration Pattern for persistence. It the solves the problem of how to map objects to a database (there are other patterns that do this too).

Factory is a Design Pattern for object creation. It abstract the complexity of instantiating an object.

There are wikipedia pages for all these 3 patterns that explain how they work. And if you want more information you can read (in order, each book explains each one of the patterns)

- Pattern-Oriented Software Architecture, A System of Patterns: Volume 1
- Enterprise Integration Patterns
- Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software

About your last question: Why so many MVC frameworks? Because all have pain points and some people think they can make a pain-free MVC framework (which is like trying to find an Unicorn)